# How to prevent double rendering on first load in Vue.js and Firebase Authentication?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

So I have my Vue instantiation wrapped around the `onAuthStateChanged` method of Firebase Auth. My code inside `main.js` file looks like this:

```
let app
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if(!app) {
    if (user) {// some actions}
    app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router,
      store,
      render: h => h(App)
    })
  }
})
```

I did this because I want to check if user is already logged in before Vue renders. While everything works perfectly, the first load renders twice and my problem is that when I have an action inside a specific page, that actions runs twice.

Preview:

[image]

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: why u dont want to call onAuthStateChanged method in created hook in your entry .js file and dispatch actions / calls functions in beforeRouterEnter hook?

Comment: you should not instantiate Vue after Firebase auth. you should do the other way round, which is instantiate Vue first then do whatever with firebase. IE: Vue to render login component if not authenticated in firebase

Comment: You'll have to show more code. With that `if(!app) {`, it makes no sense for that `app` to be instantiated twice...